# Add ActionLister to parent

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Sorry if the title does not make sense I'll try and explain in more detail below.

I have a class

```
public View implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new controls().initialise());

}
```

and a secondary class which implements the J components for a certain section within the model (EG the controls part)

```
public Controls {
    JButton button = new JButton;
// More code
}
```

Now in that **View** I would like to be able to add access that button and add a Actionlistener to it.

Currently what I am doing is adding a Getter to the Controls class and then adding the ActionListener

```
public modal implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Controls c = new controls();
    frame.add(c.initialise());
    JButton button = c.getButton();
    c.AddActionListener(this);

}
```

Which does work, although I'm getting a really bad code smell from it? So I'm wondering if there is a better way to implement this system?

**--- EDIT ---**

So I've also found this way of doing it which feels better but I'm still not sure if it is the correct practice?

It is still not ideal due to the Buttons being initialised in the main view, but if it's just the items which I need the item listener for I think thats okay?

```
public class view implements ActionListener {
    JButton jb1 = new JButton();
    JButton jb1 = new JButton();

    public view {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        Controls c = new controls();
        JPanel cView = c.initialise(jb1, jb2);
        frame.add(cView);

        jb1.addActionListener(e -> {
            //Clicked button one
        });

        jb2.addActionListener(e -> {
            //Clicked button two
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: So you mean create the button in the View and then pass it to the controls? I thought of that but I wanted to try and keep all the button code within the controls file. (Or is that bad practice?)

Comment: Are you making a M-V-C structured program? If so, buttons all belong with the view while the code that their listeners call in the control.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to. So even if I have alot of different 'sections' they should all be in the view? I can't split them into separate classes?

Comment: "It depends". What are your specific assignment requirements?

Comment: None really I'm mainly just practicing and I'd like to use MVC, although my View gots quite a few moving parts so I wanted to / thought I should split it up.